# Java and .NET: Why different sorting algorithms are used by default?

Tags: java, .net, algorithm, sorting, language-design

Just wondering why `Java` and `.NET Framework` uses different sorting algorithm by default.

**In Java** `Array.Sort()` uses [Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) algorithm by default and as [Wikipedia.com](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) says:

> In Java, the Arrays.sort() methods use merge sort or a tuned
>   quicksort depending on the datatypes and for implementation efficiency
>   switch to insertion sort when fewer than seven array elements are
>   being sorted

**In .NET Framework** `Array.Sort/List.Sort()` uses [Quick Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) as default sorting algorithm ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx)):

> List.Sort() uses Array.Sort, which uses the QuickSort algorithm. This
>   implementation performs an unstable sort; that is, if two elements are
>   equal, their order might not be preserved. In contrast, a stable sort
>   preserves the order of elements that are equal.

By looking at the great ["Comparison of algorithms"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms) table we can see that both algorithms has pretty different behaviour from Worst Case and Memory Usage perspectives:

[image]

Both `Java` and `.NET` are great Frameworks for Enterprise Solutions development, both has platforms for embedded development. So why they are using different sorting algorithm by default, any thoughts?

**EDIT:** 
I see that two persons already voted to close this quesion as not constructive. I believe Java and .NET are most popular development Frameworks so it would be really interesting to find any non trivial and interesting thoughts, perhaps facts!, regarding such decision.

Comment: Because Java and .NET are two totally different things made by two totally different companies?

Comment: +1, interesting question.  But I think it might be a better fit over at [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), as it's more of a "whiteboard question".

Comment: memory in java is 2n as the Array is copied and Lists are converted to arrays 1st.

Comment: To answer: java designers (or java.util. team) decided to use merge sort also b/c it doesn't reorder elements w/ equal order/priority, also prevents DoS attack, I remember reading about both. About .Net i guess to follow C sort.

Comment: Did nobody except me get the memo about Java7 not using MergeSort any longer? For primitives they went with a DualPivotQuicksort and for objects they use TimSort (python users should be inherently familiar with that one). Actually I'm pretty sure Java did use QuickSort in <=6 as well for some sorts - but I may remember that wrongly. And it still uses some insertion sort or so for small arrays.

Comment: Continued discussion on Programmers.SE - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/108624/java-and-net-why-different-sorting-algorithms-are-used-by-default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different development teams in two different companies came to different conclusions regarding the usual use case for their frameworks and components and have decided to implement accordingly.

Comment: Yep, can imagine this case. But I believe that enterprise solutions has a set of common problems where sorting algorithms are going to help and both mergesort and quicksort pretty different

Comment: @sll - Sun and Microsoft are different companies with different customer bases. Why would they cooperate on their separate frameworks?

Comment: No, I do not mean a cooperation, I mean that both Java and .NET are used to solve common enterprise let's say `problems` and I feel that after the deep ad independent analysis both Frameworks would find useful the same algorithm to be used as default, sorry if I expose my thoughts not pretty clear I'm not native English speaker but I'm studying :)

Comment: @sll - Chances are that each company came to _different_ conclusions from their analysis.

Comment: this point of view makes sense for me, unfortunately we can't see another opinions, looks like this question really not for SO... I hope anybody vote to reopen quesion or help to reformulate it to be accepted as constructive, who knows... anyway thanks Oded!